# android HTC one menu doesn't show

Tags: android, menu, android-menu

I have an application running correctly in all the devices with a physical **menu** button. Few days before I installed that app in a HTC One (Android 4) and the menu just disappeared from my app. On other apps that have a menu add the 3 points menu indicator in action bar.

I don't want to put here the code, because it is nothing special... just a simple menu, added inside onCreateOptionsMenu method. **What should I do to fix this issue for HTC One?**

The menu appears on other devices running Android 4 (like Galaxy s3) with physical menu button.

Answer (score 1):

> Few days before I installed that app in a HTC One (Android 4) and the menu just disappeared from my app. On other apps that have a menu add the 3 points menu indicator in action bar.

Devices with an off-screen MENU button usually will not have the "3 points menu indicator in the action bar". Users access the overflow by pressing that MENU button.

For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo) has an overflow. When running on a device or emulator with an off-screen MENU button, there is no "3 points menu indicator in the action bar":

[image: Action bar, with overflow, on emulator with off-screen MENU button]

> What should I do to fix this issue for HTC One?

Well, my HTC One S does not have MENU button. Presumably you have some other version of the HTC One series that does have a MENU button. If so, you can press the MENU button:

[image: Action bar, with overflow, on emulator with off-screen MENU button, after having pressed said button]

> The menu appears on other devices running Android 4 (like Galaxy s3) with physical menu button.

That was the decision of those device manufacturers, then, for those specific devics.

For the record, here is the app on a Galaxy Nexus (no off-screen MENU button):

[image: Action bar, with overflow, on Galaxy Nexus]

Here is the app on an HTC One S (no off-screen MENU button, illustrating a bug where the overflow is shown in the action bar *and* in a nav bar):

[image: Action bar, with overflow, on HTC One S]

Here is the app with [the fix applied](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html), on that HTC One S:

[image: Action bar, with fixed overflow, on HTC One S]

Here is the app on a Nexus S (with an off-screen MENU button):

[image: Action bar, with fixed overflow, on Nexus S]

Here is the app on a Galaxy Note II (with an off-screen MENU button):

[image: Action bar, with fixed overflow, on Galaxy Note II]

As you can see, in many cases, the existence of an off-screen MENU button suppresses the "3 points menu indicator in the action bar".

Comment: Thanks for all those details, but I still don't get the way to fix my issue. How do I force the 3 dots indicator to be visible? I have the rest of the onscreen buttons (home, back and some middle button to minimize my app). I should get the 3 dots on a side to allow me to open the menu? Do I have any way to customize this action bar?

Comment: @ZelterAdy: "I still don't get the way to fix my issue" -- that is because there is no issue and nothing to fix. Your current behavior is correct. It is what your users will expect, as it will work how all the rest of their apps on their device works. "How do I force the 3 dots indicator to be visible?" -- you can't force it in the action bar.

Comment: @ZelterAdy: "I have the rest of the onscreen buttons (home, back and some middle button to minimize my app)" -- the only way to force the overflow indicator to be in a navigation bar, if one is available, is to set your `android:targetSdkVersion` low enough. `13` may work, `10` should work.